# Running Matlab Command From Tcl

Tags: matlab, tcl

From my TCL script I like to open Matlab command window and display if its Matlab win32 or win64.

Therefore I use the following command:

```
exec {*}matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r  "arch = computer; fprintf('%s \n', arch')";
```

However I keep getting error:

```
arch = computer; fprintf('%s 
                          |
Error: String is not terminated properly.
```

**If I run the same in Matlab no issues.**

Could some kindly advice.

Thanks

Anj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl is substituting the `\n` before handing the command to matlab. Escape it:

```
exec matlab ... -r  "arch = computer; fprintf('%s \\n', arch')"
```

Or use braces

```
exec matlab ... -r  {arch = computer; fprintf('%s \n', arch')}
```